# Multiple sheets and time periods for vlookup and if formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a multi page spreadsheet and want to achieve the following.

On the summary page I want it to look up the values that are deducted from the other sheets and reported. That part to me seems like a simple vlookup but where I confuse myself is when I do this.

Let’s say sheets 2 and 3 are identical (they represent two different locations) so they both have deductions at the same time. On the summary page I want to add those deductions together to report one total.

Now say sheets 4 and 5 all started 10 and 20 periods after sheet 1 I want to add the deductions together that occurred at the same time. This is where I thought an IF formula would be needed but my messy solution is an extra column that represents the original period. Say sheet 1 is 1-50 but sheet 4 started at period 10 then it’s behind 10 so if had an extra column that was original 1-50 the deductions would only need to look at the original period column.

If I do this the long way it is a bloom up for each sheet and I have 50 sheets so I’m trying to find a neater solution. In my mind that is clear and I hope someone can give me just the long way around solution

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the assistance.

Answer was to create a shorter list, and then a number of other formulas